# Triple integral positive octant

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to evaluate this integral over the portion of the positive octant
cut off by the plane $x + y + z = \pi$. $$\iiint \sin(x+y+z)\, dx\, dy\,dz$$ What boundaries do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working in the positive octant $$ x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0$$

You're other condition is $$ x + y + z \leq \pi $$

Rewriting it: $ z \leq \pi - x - y $

Results in $ z \leq \pi $

Similarly, for any $z$: $ y \leq \pi - x - z \leq \pi - z $

And for any $z$ and $y$: $ x \leq \pi - y - z $

Therefore your boundary conditions are:
$$ 0 \leq z \leq \pi $$
$$ 0 \leq y \leq \pi - z $$
$$ 0 \leq x \leq \pi - y - z $$

You're integral then becomes:
$$ \int_0^\pi \int_0^{\pi-z} \int_0^{\pi -y-z} \sin (x+y+z)dxdydz$$

Which is equal to 
$$ \frac{\pi ^2}2 - 2 $$

Answer (score 1):

The boundaries are

- $z=0$ and $z(x,y)=\pi-x-y$
- $y=0$ and $y(x)=\pi-x$
- $x=0$ and $x=\pi$